# Is there an easy way to provide parameters to an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

What's the best way to configure parameters for a SSIS package? (I.e. what's common/easy/simple)

I am developing an SSIS package and I want to specify the location of a folder to watch for source files. I want to make it as easy as possible for those who deploy the SSIS package.

For example, I see that it's easy to specify connection strings for connection managers using dtexecui, but I don't see a place for parameters. i.e. none of the variables show up in the "Set Values" tab.

I looked at package configurations but it seems they have to be created by a SSIS developer and not the SSIS package runner/deployer (I may be missing something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package configurations are created by the developer but they populate either an SQL table, an XML file, the registry or environment variables.  So the selection of which values are populated is up to the developer but the actual values can be changed at deployment.

I've found that the best combination is to have the package configurations in an SQL table with the connection string for that table in an environment variable.  That way you can maintain different environments for testing and production.

Comment: Note that your connection string and variables can also be specified in the call to the package, i.e. in the job step that is going to execute it. I have done both ways, if the package has a single set of source/target locations then a configuration table and connection string for this table based on environment variable works well. However, if the same package needs to be run repeatedly with different configurations (distributing the same set of data to multiple locations) then setting the values in the job step usually works better, the trick is getting the syntax correct.

Comment: @Rowzel - I used to do it like that but stopped when I came across a client whose standard security setup was really weird and for some reason we weren't able to get the information from the job step.

Answer (score 3):

you can store them in a table and then dynamically populate the variables at runtime from the table with an Execute SQL Task, this way you don't have to modify the package

To add a variable View-->Other Windows-->Variables, then click on the Add variable icon (the  top left one)

Comment: I never thought of that! I'll definitely consider that. It's a shame that there isn't an SSIS solution that looks any easier than "Update the values in this table".

Comment: There are other ways like configuration files, but a table seems easier to me, especially if someone needs to update the values but doesn't have access to the SQL Agent job or package

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a simple and easy way to make configurable parameter passing simple for users/deployers to configure. The following is an outline of a semi-complex one I made a few years back.

A SQL Agent job regularly calls a stored procedure that does some checks and, when necessary, prepares data, launches an SSIS package, and passes the prepared data into the package via parameters; the values are either derived from the work-at-hand or from database "configuration tables" that IT configures on a per-enviornment basis. Given the nature of our scaled-out environment it was simpler to use parameters passed into the package than it was to try and have the package figure out where to go for its data.

Calling the package was done by building a complex script and passing it as a parameter to xp_cmdshell. `DTEXEC` is the executable to call, and it has mandatory and optional switches, such as /File to specify where the package is. To work parameters, I defined variables sich as "FilesFolder" and "EMail_SMTPServer" within the package, and then passed in values to them with the /Set switch, like so:

```
    SET @Command = 'DTEXEC'
     + ' /File "' + @PackageLocation + '\' + @PackageName + '"'
     + ' /Set \package.variables[FilesFolder].Value;"' + @FilesFolder + '"'
     + ' /Set \package.variables[EMail_SMTPServer].Value;' + @SMTPServer
```

/Set replaces their their Value property with the specified value. Note the extra " quotes for FilesFolder, to account for embedded spaces in the name.

This was pretty fussy to implement--I recall having loads of fun getting semicolon-delimited email addressees working properly. Thing is, it's been running smoothly for about 2 years now on several environments, and setting up a new one is a documented and thus relatively pain-free process.

There are many ways this kind of functionality can be done, this is only one of them.

Comment: Thanks Philip, I think you hit the nail on the head with when you said "I don't think there is a simple and easy way ..." It answers the question most directly. :-)

Comment: The question "how to make it simplest for *my* users to use" is the important one, and ultimately only you can answer it. Hopefully our suggestions help!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a variables tab in SSMS which allows you to specify the variable to set the values for.

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious. I don't see it.

Comment: View-->Other Windows-->Variables

Comment: Yes, I see the variables tab in BIDS (or visual studio in my case). But I don't know how to make it easy for deployers to provide the values. (They'll know the values, but I don't ahead of time).

Comment: Are you trying to set them set the values when it's schedule via a SQL Agent job or when run via a command line?